# Is there a way to add a column of percentage of total count into R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
  Phytoplankton    Count 
1        Diatom  2073.70   
2      Dinoflag     0.68    
3         Synch  5961.00    
4          Peuk 18699.00    
5          Neuk  2160.00
```

Is there a way to add a column that gives the relative percentage of each group of the total sum of the count?

I can do it manually but was wondering if there was a command that totals one column and then finds the proportions?

Thanks

Comment: `df$Percentage <- 100 * df$Count/sum(df$Count)` (where obviously you need to substitute `df` for whatever your data frame is called)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr`, we can `mutate` a new column to get the relative abundance. If you want the percent sign as well, then we can use `scales::label_percent()`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(freq = scales::label_percent()(Count / sum(Count)))

#  Phytoplankton    Count   freq
#1        Diatom  2073.70  7.18%
#2      Dinoflag     0.68  0.00%
#3         Synch  5961.00 20.63%
#4          Peuk 18699.00 64.72%
#5          Neuk  2160.00  7.48%
```

Or if you don't want the percent sign, then we can just do the simple calculation.

```
df %>%
  mutate(freq = (Count / sum(Count))*100)

#  Phytoplankton    Count         freq
#1        Diatom  2073.70  7.176828158
#2      Dinoflag     0.68  0.002353399
#3         Synch  5961.00 20.630309423
#4          Peuk 18699.00 64.715006863
#5          Neuk  2160.00  7.475502156
```

Or with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

dt[, freq := prop.table(Count)*100]
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Phytoplankton = c("Diatom", "Dinoflag", "Synch", 
"Peuk", "Neuk"), Count = c(2073.7, 0.68, 5961, 18699, 2160)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```